# Is Facebook long-lived access token usable on multiple users?

Tags: php, facebook, yii, facebook-php-sdk

I'm experimenting with Facebook's long-live access token and I found that the long-lived access token is usable in different users. Is this normal?

I'm using the Facebook PHP SDK v3.2.2 and Yii. Here's my code to generate the long-lived access token from `App_User_1`

```
Yii::import('application.vendors.facebook.Facebook');
$facebook = new Facebook(
    array(
        'appId' => Yii::app()->params['facebookApi'],
        'secret' => Yii::app()->params['facebookSecretCode'],
        'cookie' => true,
    )
);
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('display' => 'touch', 'scope' => 'publish_actions'));
$fbUser = $facebook->getUser();
if(!empty($fbUser))
{
    $facebook->setExtendedAccessToken(); //long-live access_token 60 days
    $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    exit(print_r($access_token));
}
```

Here's my code to test posting to `App_User_1`'s Facebook wall.

```
$message = "A message";
$link = "http://www.alink.com";
$picture = "http://www.alink/image.png";
$sendTo = "`**App_User_1**`";
$access_token = "xxxxxxxxxx";

Yii::import('application.vendors.facebook.Facebook');
$facebook = new Facebook(
    array(
        'appId' => Yii::app()->params['facebookApi'],
        'secret' => Yii::app()->params['facebookSecretCode'],
        'cookie' => true,
    )
);

$attachment = array('message' => $message, 'link' => $link, 'picture' => $picture );
$api = "/$sendTo/feed/?access_token='.$access_token,";
$result = $facebook->api($api,'post', $attachment);
```

I have 2 test app user. If I substitute the `App_User_1`'s access token, I can also post into `App_User_2`'s Facebook Wall. Is this normal?

Comment: If by posting you mean posting to app_user_2's wall as user app_user_1, then yes.

Comment: Hi @JoachimIsaksson, correct me if I'm wrong. But isn't the long-lived access token unique to each user? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but app_user_1 could post to app_user_2's wall, if they're friends. At least my friends post on mine for my birthday every year ;)

Comment: Post to friends wall by PHP sdk had been depreciated in 6 feb Migration. Please check [developers roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Not really. app_user_1 is not friends with app_user_2 at all. What I did was logging on as app_user_1 and get his long-lived access token and then log off. With app_user_1's long-lived access token, I'm able to post into app_user_1's wall and app_user_2's wall as an app. This is what I find odd.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have been doing this the wrong way. Using the PHP SDK, the `api` method does not recognize the access_token as part of its path parameter. (`e.g. /me/feed/?access_token=blah`)

Instead, the access token should be specified under optional parameters in an array format.

Here's how I got mine to work.

```
$facebook_uid = '1234567890';
//Initialize array for the params parameter
$fb_data = array();
$fb_data['access_token'] = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
$fb_data['message'] = 'A test message';
$facebook->api('/'.$facebook_uid.'/feed/', 'post', $fb_data);
```

Tried swapping the access token with other app user's access token and not specifying access_token at all. Both will result in error (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action.

I would also recommend using this tool by Facebook to verify that the access_token is generated correctly by your app. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug